# "Recursive Makefile Considered Harmful" style makefile issues

Tags: c++, makefile

I am having some troubles getting my program to build using a `makefile` inspired by the [Recursive Makefile Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper.

I am quite new to `makefile`s, and I am able to get it all to build fine, however there are a couple of things that aren't working that, from my understanding, should be working. I was hoping that you guys/gals would be able to either clarify that things for me!

I am running OSX. Using g++ to compile (or at least, intending to). Here is the relevant `makefile` and `depend.sh`

**makefile**

```
CC = g++
MODULES := src Engine Engine/core Engine/render
# look for include files in
# each of the modules
CFLAGS := $(patsubst %,-I%,$(MODULES)) -I/usr/local/include/SDL2/
# extra libraries if required
LIBS := -lm -L/usr/local/lib/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image
# each module will add to this
SRC :=
# include the description for
# each module
include $(patsubst %,%/module.mk,$(MODULES))
# determine the object files
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o, $(filter %.cpp,$(SRC))) #\
#$(patsubst %.y,%.o, \
#$(filter %.y,$(SRC)))
# link the program
main: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS)
# include the C++ include
# dependencies
include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
# calculate C++ include
# dependencies
%.d: %.cpp
    ./depend.sh ‘dirname $*.cpp‘ $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp > $@

clean:
    find ./ -iname "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
    find ./ -iname "*.d" -exec rm {} \;
    rm main
```

**depend.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$1"
shift 1
case "$DIR" in 
"" | ".")
g++ -MM -MG "$@" | 
sed -e ’s@ˆ\(.*\)\.o:@\1.d \1.o:@’
;;
*)
g++ -MM -MG "$@" | 
sed -e "s@ˆ\(.*\)\.o:@$DIR/\1.d $DIR/\1.o:@"
;;
esac
```

**1. Include Directories**

I am using SDL2 in my application to handle windows and other media functionality. I have my SDL2 include directory installed at `/usr/local/include/SDL2/`. So in my CFLAGS I have `-I/usr/local/include/SDL2/`. In a previous, very simple `makefile` this worked. The SDL directory was included and my code files that were including SDL headers worked as expected. But using the makefile above, the SDL include directory seems to be **completely** ignored! I need to use absolute paths in my code files to include SDL (ie. Include directory ignored, correct?).

My work around has been to create a symlink in my working directory and use relative paths to access that, but that is far from ideal... Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

**2. Modules**

At this point it seems as though I need to update the top-level `MODULES` variable to include pretty much every folder in my project. I have tried to append child folders to the respective `module.mk` file but that had no effect. Eg. I also removed the `Engine/core` and `Engine/render` modules from the top-level `makefile`, then in the `module.mk` file found in the `Engine` folder, I had:

```
MODULES += Engine/core Engine/render
```

My thinking is that the top-level `makefile` would see that there is an `Engine` module, it would check the `Engine` folder, open up the `module.mk` file, and see that there were 2 more modules. Is this incorrect?

**A strange observation**

In my `makefile` I define `CC` as `g++`. I then use `$(CC)` in the `main` target. I also specify g++ in `depend.sh`. However when I build successfully, I get a bunch of these errors:

```
./depend.sh ‘dirname src/main.cpp‘ -Isrc -IJEngine -IEngine/core -IEngine/render -I/usr/local/include/SDL2/ src/main.cpp > src/main.d
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/main.cpp‘'
```

Followed by success:

```
c++    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
c++    -c -o Engine/Engine.o Engine/Engine.cpp
c++    -c -o Engine/core/Error.o Engine/core/Error.cpp
c++    -c -o Engine/core/Window.o Engine/core/Window.cpp
c++    -c -o Engine/render/Render.o Engine/render/Render.cpp
g++ -o main src/main.o Engine/Engine.o Engine/core/Error.o Engine/core/Window.o Engine/render/Render.o  -lm -L/usr/local/lib/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -Isrc -IEngine -IEngine/core -IEngine/render -I/usr/local/include/SDL2/
```

Yay! It built! And it runs! But what were those errors? And why is `c++` being used for everything except the last call and not `g++`? I haven't specified `c++` anywhere (i think!)

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I am missing any necessary information.

Comment: Not an answer, but anything against using a proper build system? CMake or Scons?

Comment: @OneofOne Nothing at all! I'm just learning how to build my applications without the aid of Visual Studio/Xcode, or something of the like. I'll look into them, thanks! (future readers, of course, I'm still curious about the question above!)

Comment: [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)/[Scons](http://www.scons.org/wiki/SconsTutorial1) don't use visual uis, I highly recommend looking into them for future projects because it will make your compile system portable.

Comment: @OneOfOne Thanks for the heads up! I will consider them for this project depending on what answers I get ;)

Comment: I'm strongly inclined to agree with @OneOfOne, from first-hand experience (I've been down the path you're currently going down, and it's not pleasant).  IMHO, manual creation of makefiles should have been consigned to the history books at least 15 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The `CC` variable refers to the c compiler not the C++ compiler.  For cpp files, make will use the value of `CXX` which defaults to `c++`.  That's why you see c++ in the output.  `CC` is also used for linking, which is why you see the value of `CC` as the last line of output.

If you want to use g++ for the cpp files (assume you do?), set `CXX` instead of (or addition to) `CC`.

You can see all the implicit rules and variables by running `make -p` in a directory with no makefiles.

I believe the `dirname` argument to `depend.sh` should have no quotes around it.  You want to pass the directory in.

UPDATE:
I should have noted that CFLAGS is used by the implicit .c file recipe, but not for the .cpp file recipe.  So your CFLAGS -I is ignored when compiling your cpp files.  You need to set CXXFLAGS instead.